# blog to show up under newly created page

Tags: wordpress, blogs

1. I created a blog site at wordpress.com.
2. I create a new page (XYZ).
3. I created a blog entry but don't see any option so that this blog entry appears under new page. It just add under the Home page.

Any ideas how can i add a blog entry so it shows up in a new page?

Comment: You might have more chance on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both wordpress.com and self-hosted Wordpress:

> Dashboard>>Settings>>Reading>> Front page displays....

Answer (score -1):

Normally Wordpress shows "the loop," the latest blog posts, on the front page. It considers "pages" to be static pages that don't change.

I think a good way to do what you want is to post blogs under a specific category and then edit the page.php file to display a loop of only blog posts in a specific category. There might be a theme that does that a little easier if you want to dig around.

If writing code and digging for themes doesn't sound too appealing you might have better luck with a Drupal site. It would be more GUI oriented.